Cannot install sorbet-static with bundler >= 2.4 on M1
Bundle fails to resolve dependencies of sorbet when using bundler 2.4 or later on macos. It works fine in docker with all bundler versions.
Works fine with bundler 2.3:

Use MRI ruby, for example: asdf local ruby 3.1.6. I got the same issue with ruby 3.2 (did not test with ruby 3.3 because all our projects are still on ruby 3.1).
Install bundler gem install bundler -v 2.3.27
Create a Gemfile with this content:

source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sorbet', '>= 0.5.11647'


bundle install fails:

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'sorbet-static (= 0.5.11647)' with platform 'ruby', which is required by gem 'sorbet (>= 0.5.11647)', in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally.

The source contains the following gems matching 'sorbet-static (= 0.5.11647)':
  * sorbet-static-0.5.11647-aarch64-linux
  * sorbet-static-0.5.11647-java
  * sorbet-static-0.5.11647-universal-darwin
  * sorbet-static-0.5.11647-x86_64-linux


Add darwin platform to resolve issue: bundle lock --add-platform universal-darwin
bundle install works now:

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Using bundler 2.3.27
Fetching sorbet-static 0.5.11647 (universal-darwin)
Installing sorbet-static 0.5.11647 (universal-darwin)
Fetching sorbet 0.5.11647
Installing sorbet 0.5.11647
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 3 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

If we do the same with bundler 2.4.0 for example then we get the following error at step 6:
Resolving dependencies...
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'sorbet-static (= 0.5.11647)' with platforms 'ruby', 'universal-darwin' in locally installed gems.

The source contains the following gems matching 'sorbet-static (= 0.5.11647)':
  * sorbet-static-0.5.11647-universal-darwin

The error message is different in bundler 2.4.22 (and bundler 2.5 seems to show this error as well):
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gems matching 'sorbet-static (= 0.5.11647)' valid for all resolution platforms (ruby, universal-darwin) in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally.

The source contains the following gems matching 'sorbet-static (= 0.5.11647)':
  * sorbet-static-0.5.11647-aarch64-linux
  * sorbet-static-0.5.11647-java
  * sorbet-static-0.5.11647-universal-darwin
  * sorbet-static-0.5.11647-x86_64-linux

Can this be resolved? The docs says apple silicon isn't supported, but based on the above error the issue isn't related to M1. Any help is appreciated.
Edit: add output of bundle platform
bundle platform
Your platform is: arm64-darwin-22

Your app has gems that work on these platforms:
* ruby
* universal-darwin

Your Gemfile does not specify a Ruby version requirement.


FWIW Apple Silicon builds are supported since 0.5.11577, but the docs were outdated: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/8305

I am not 100% sure what the question is but what does bundle platform show? It appears that bundler is trying to fall back to the ruby platform; however sorbet-static states that it is platform dependent due to the fact that the binaries are pre-built.

I added the output of bundle platform above. The output is the same for bundler 2.3, 2.4 and 2.5. Executing bundle lock --remove-platform ruby does not remove ruby from the bundle platform output (i guess because i'm using MRI ruby).
